# How to migrate revisions

Tags: nodes, 8, migrations

I'm migrating contents from D7 to D8. I'm exporting nodes with services_views and importing with migrate.

I would like to import also revisions. How should I do? Revisions on D8 don't seem entities, so what kind of "target" should I use to import them?

Answer (score 5):

The revisions are added to the existing entity. There is an [EntityRevision](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21destination%21EntityRevision.php/class/EntityRevision/8.2.x) destination in core.

See `core/modules/node/migration_templates/d7_node_revision.yml` [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!migration_templates!d7_node_revision.yml/8.2.x) for an example of how you'd migrate revisions.

Note: translated node revisions are not yet supported, but you can look at a good starting point at [#2746541](https://www.drupal.org/node/2746541).

Comment: For anyone arriving here, there's also a new(ish) 'complete' migration for nodes that takes revisions and translations into account: https://www.drupal.org/node/3105503

Comment: Also, consider this 10.2 and 11.x change regarding entity revisions, https://www.drupal.org/node/3426397